# How to extract an object from a List of object in Java 8?

Tags: java, stream

I have a list of object A (Folder). Each object A in this list has a list of object B (Partners) and the object B has also a list of Object C (Personnes). The object C contains an attribute code that i want to use to filter using java 8.

I've tried the code bellow but it doesnt seem to work :

```
A objectA = new A();
String code = "O";
for (A a: listObjectsA) {
    for (B b: a.getPartners()) {
        for (C c: b.getPersonnes()) {
            if (c.getCode().equalsIgnoreCase(code)) {
                objectA = a;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do you guys have an idea how can i use FlatMap to do this kind of conversion from `List<A>` to `A` ?

Comment: You need to use nested streams and a sequence of `anyMatch` calls at those three levels.

Comment: When you need to exit from more than one loop it is not enough to use 'break' keyword alone. In your example you are only breaking out of the inner most loop. You can add a label to the outer most loop to break out of the whole nested loop.

Answer (score 1):

It does not work because the `break` instruction stops just the last `for` loop.

You can use `break` with a label that stops exactly the loop you want.

```java
A objectA = new A();
String code = "O";
loopA: for (A a: listObjectsA) {
    for (B b: a.getPartners()) {
        for (C c: b.getPersonnes()) {
            if (c.getCode().equalsIgnoreCase(code)) {
                objectA = a;
                break loopA;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can encapsulate the method using `return` and `Optional`.

```java
public class Example {

    public String getObjectA() {
        String code = "O";
        for (A a: listObjectsA) {
            for (B b: a.getPartners()) {
                for (C c: b.getPersonnes()) {
                    if (c.getCode().equalsIgnoreCase(code)) {
                        return Optional.of(a);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Optional<A> objectA = getObjectA();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We use filter on the top-level stream, checking inner streams using `anyMatch` as your search is to find any matching object:

```
A objectA = listObjectsA.stream().filter(a -> a.getPartners()
                .stream()
                .anyMatch(b -> b.getPersonnes()
                        .stream()
                        .anyMatch(c -> c.getCode().equalsIgnoreCase(code)))) 
        .findFirst()
        .orElseGet(A::new); //defaults to new A()
```

You can't use a simple `flatMap` as it'd transform the stream to `B` and `C` types in turn, making it rather complicated to return to the parent `A` object you want to return.